# How to convert GetDate() in 1 Jan 2014 format?

Tags: sql

I using a query where I am selecting some attributes from the table based on a where condition. My where condition is-

```
date>GetDate();
```

I have tried this-

```
SELECT TOP 2 img,name,substring(description,1,80) as
description,Convert(nvarchar,date,106) as date 
FROM tbl_test 
where date>=Convert(nvarchar,GetDate(),106) 
order by date Asc;
```

This query is running fine but showing different result as compared to a different query of similar kind in which I am not converting the date format.

```
SELECT TOP 2 img,name,substring(description,1,80) as description,date 
FROM tbl_test 
where date>=GetDate() 
order by date Asc;
```

Please guide me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: I am using thing query in SQL Server Mr. Mureinik.

Comment: what datatype is your `Date` column is `Datetime` or just `Date` ???

Comment: I would suggest reading [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) by Aaron Bertrand about mishandling date range queries. It seems to apply perfectly to your situation. If you have a few minutes to kill you may want to read the entire bad habits to kick series, it is very informative and I don't think there is a single sentiment in any of the articles that I don't agree with.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Gareth. The post was very interesting and very useful as well. I get to know about much of a stuff in SQL which I was not knowing earlier.

Comment: @UpendraChaudhari : Yes of course I will definitely do that. But please clear my confusion, I still did not get what I am expecting. I mentioned the problem under the comment section of your post Mr. Upendra. Please Check.

Comment: @Omi : Ok, if you have confusion in result like 2 dates should be come of Jan month not March month then you can get it by changing alias of "as [date] to "as [DisplayDate]". See here : sqlfiddle.com/#!3/579ce/10 (It was problem of same names for date field and date alias) otherwise apply 102 format in order by clause also. Check this : sqlfiddle.com/#!3/579ce/5

Comment: @UpendraChaudhari : Thanks a lot Mr. Upendra. Finally it is done.I am very thankful to you sir. Thanks for your patience and continuous help. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query will convert getdate() into nvarchar data type and it will compare date with string while 2nd query will compare 2 dates. **So 2nd option is better.** Still if you want to convert date into string then check then use 102 format like

`WHERE CONVERT(varchar(20),date,102) >= CONVERT(varchar(20), getdate(),102)`

For select column you can use format which you want like

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20),date,106)
```

**Final Query is :**

```
SELECT  TOP 2 
        img,
        name,
        SUBSTRING(description,1,80) as description,
        CONVERT(varchar(20),date,106) as [DisplayDate]
FROM tbl_test 
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(20),date,102) >= CONVERT(varchar(20), getdate(),102)
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

**Without convert to varchar, you can cast getdate() to date to remove time part :**

```
SELECT  TOP 2 
        img,
        name,
        SUBSTRING(description,1,80) as description,
        CONVERT(varchar(20),date,106) as [DisplayDate]
FROM tbl_test 
WHERE date >= CAST(getdate() as date)
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/579ce/10)**

Comment: Hello Mr. Upendra
A very Happy New Year to you, Thanks for ur reply.And yes ur right I know that but why there is a difference in the result?I believe both the query should give same result.

Comment: No, it will not give same result. string compare and date compare are 2 different things. If you want to get same result then use 102 format.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Upendra Chaudhari.
Now I am gettin same result in both the cases.But what if I want to show the result in this format- 1 Jan 2014?
How can I do this with the same query?

Comment: No, try format 106 in select and format 102 in where clause which I have mentioned. Also apply format at both side in where clause. please check my answer.

Comment: `TOP 2 img,name,substring(description,1,80) as description,Convert(varchar(20),date,106) as date FROM tbl_test where date>=Convert(varchar(20),GetDate(),102) order by date Asc` Result is- 03 Mar 2014 and 06 Jan 2014
Whereas when I tried- 
`SELECT TOP 2 img,name,substring(description,1,80) as description,Convert(varchar(20),date,102) as date FROM tbl_test where date>=Convert(varchar(20),GetDate(),102) order by date Asc` Result is- 2014.01.06 and 2014.01.08
Please Guide me Mr. Upendra why there is a difference in the result.

Comment: If you compare date with string then it will always give wrong result due to time. Check your both cases in demo : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6b6f/3

Comment: Sorry Mr. Upendra I was checking your answer in comment. I tried what you suggested but still same old answer is reflecting.
Result is 03 Mar 2014 and 06 Jan 2014
Whereas I am expecting 06 Jan 2014 and 08 Jan 2014

Comment: Hello Mr. Updendra,
Your post was very interesting and helpful also. But I still did not got what I am expecting. Please check this SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/579ce/1 
In this I have added two new rows. And the query is same as you suggested. But see there is a difference in the result. Why is this happening? Logically it should reflect 5th Jan 2014 and 8th Jan 2014

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Date Datetime;
SET @Date = GETDATE();
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @Date, 113) AS Date
```

**RESULT**

```
╔══════════════╗
║     Date     ║
╠══════════════╣
║ 01 Jan 2014  ║
╚══════════════╝
```

**Edit**

as Upendra Chaudhari has explained that when you do comparing column `Date` with a string `=Convert(varchar(20),GetDate(),102)`,

what is actually happening behind the scenes is `Convert(varchar(20),GetDate(),102)` returns a string `2014.01.01` but to compare this string with a Datetime column SQL Server does an implicit conversion to compare both values. Sql Server have to have both values in the same datatype to compare them.

Now datatype Datetime has Precedence over nvarchar/varchar datatype so sql server converts the string into datetime datatype which returns something like

```
SELECT CAST('2014.01.01' AS DATETIME) 
Result : 2014-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Now in this process of converting your values to string and then back to datetime you have actually lost all the time values in your comparing values. and this is the reason why you are getting unexpected results back.

so make sure whenever you are comparing to have exactly the same datatype on both sides and take control of any data conversions in your code rather then sql server doing datatype conversions for you.

I hope this will explain you why you are getting different results .

Comment: Hello Mr. M.Ali,
Actually the problem is not with the format.Problem is with the result.
I tried this query
`SELECT TOP 2 img,name,substring(description,1,80) as description,Convert(varchar(20),date,106) as date FROM tbl_test where date>=Convert(varchar(20),GetDate(),102) order by date Asc`
Result is- 03 Mar 2014 and 06 Jan 2014
Whereas when I tried-
`SELECT TOP 2 img,name,substring(description,1,80) as description,Convert(varchar(20),date,102) as date FROM tbl_test where date>=Convert(varchar(20),GetDate(),102) order by date Asc`
Result is- 2014.01.06 and 2014.01.08

Comment: Please guide me why I am getting two different results?

Comment: @Omi have a look now I have tried to explain why you are getting these different unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. M.Ali
I was very curious to know about this backhand process which was going and I was not able trace it. Your post was very helpful.Thanks again for explaining it in simple and clear way.Cheers :-)

Comment: @Omi well if it helped you then you should accept it as an answer :)

Comment: @M.Ali : Hello, Is it possible to accept to post as correct answer??
actually post of Mr. Upendra was also very helpful. The SQL Fiddle which he gave cleared my doubt totally. Thanks a lot for your support friend. I am very hapy to mark your post as answer.

Comment: When I posted that comment you haven't had accepted any answer but you should accept the post as an answer which help you most whether it's mine or someone else's don't want no favouritism here :)

Comment: O yes you cannot accept two answers but you can up vote an answer if you think it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
where date>=CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 113)
```

Comment: Hello Mr. MillaresRoo,
I tried this but the result is different from what I am expecting.